# Linux Debian Screen is terminating. Can't open screen

Tags: linux, debian, gnu-screen

I use `PuTTY` to connect with my VPS server that runs on Debian 7.0 When I try open screen by

```
screen -S {screenName}
```

after enter there's just info `[screen is terminating]`.

It happens on all accounts apart from root.

Comment: What happens if you do not use the `-S screenName` option? If your preferred screen name includes blanks, did you set it in quotes?

Comment: I don't have a definitive idea, but I'd suspect a problem with permissions: either `screen` fails to create a (Unix-domain) socket (which is a filesystem object, among other things) or it fails to create a pseudoterminal (PTY) -- check the access rights on the `/dev/ptmx` device (and check if `/dev/pts` is mounted at all) -- it should be `root:root` `0666`.

Comment: (A followup) on a randomly picked Wheezy systems I have in the vicinity, `screen` creates its sockets under the `/run/screen/S-<username>` directory: for instance, while being logged as `kostix` in a host `jukebox`, I have this socket created by `screen`: `/run/screen/S-kostix/5523.pts-0.jukebox`

Comment: And you could also try to install `tmux` (it's a supposedly better `screen`) and try it to see if it may be it would print a more sensible error message should it fail to start.

Comment: Before you do anything else, here's a troubleshooting tip:  run  "echo $TMOUT" (without the quotes).  If it returns a number, the system is configured to terminate sessions after a certain amount of inactivity.

Comment: Yeah, I realize that this issue was posted over 9 years ago but there's not a good troubleshooting tip in any of the responses (e.g., /dev permissions don't change by themselves).

Yes, replacing screen with tmux might work, if the problem is internal to screen.  However, if it's the system that's causing it (e.g., the TMOUT variable is set), then his system will still be borked.

Comment: @joatd it's very difficult to troubleshoot when the original poster doesn't respond to any of the suggestions. At that point I for one would have just shrugged and walked away. VTC as "cannot reproduce" if you like and then ask your own question afresh

Answer (score 0):

Could you check that you don't have a line about `/dev/pts` in your `/etc/fstab` file like

```
devpts      /dev/pts    devpts  defaults    0   0
```

that would override the one from `/etc/mtab` like

```
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
```

If so, try commenting the one from `/etc/fstab`, this could help.
In any case, the `mount` command should show you the correct rights for `/dev/pts`, like

```
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
```